# I cannot find PostSharp.Patterns

Tags: postsharp

I downloaded and installed Postsharp the essentials version which according to the matrix on their website includes caching.

I added it to my project by right clicking and selecting the Add Postsharp option.

When I go into my project to play with testing and I type:

```
using PostSharp.Patterns
```

Patterns is not an option for me, I have Aspects, Collections, Constraints... but no Patterns.

Am I missing a reference, is this a license issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostSharp is split into multiple NuGet packages. Selecting "Add PostSharp to project" only installs the core package (`PostSharp`). In your case, you need to install `PostSharp.Patterns.Caching`. Please note that you will also need to specify the caching backend, see [the documentation on caching](http://doc.postsharp.net/caching-getting-started).